# Associativity of word_cat from Word.thy

Tags: isabelle

I am having trouble proving that the `word_cat` function from Word.thy is associative.  This fact seems to be missing from the Word theory itself (or at least `find_theorems` and a manual browse of the theory reveals nothing relevant), but I require this lemma to proceed in the proof of another theorem.

More specifically, for the following lemma:

```
lemma word_cat_assoc:
  fixes b1 :: "'a::len word" and b2 :: "'b::len word" and b3 :: "'c::len word"
  shows "word_cat b1 (word_cat b2 b3) = word_cat (word_cat b1 b2) b3"
sorry
```

I'm not even sure how best to proceed, here.  I have used `find_theorems` to identify that the lemmas `word_eq_iff` and `word_cat_bl` may be of interest, but any attempt to proceed with these lemmas creates a massive mess.  Does anybody have any hints?

More generally, it seems to me that working with the Word library itself is quite awkward, and I would appreciate any tips for working with it.  I have at several points in my proofs required a case analysis on the result of a `word_split w` for some `w`.  Using `case_tac` causes problems here as new type variables are invented for the word length type variables.  Instead, I have to resort to a roundabout form of case analysis, first introducing a cut with `subgoal_tac` with explicit lengths, like so:

```
apply(subgoal_tac "∃b3::8 word. ∃b4::8 word. word_split b1 = (b3, b4)")
```

and then proceeding using this fact.  Presumably there is a better way to work with the library than this?

Comment: I just attempted to prove it, but failed. The obvious attempt (by induction over the length of the word) doesn't work, because you can't put a type into the 'arbitrary' clause.

Comment: @larsrh yeah that's what I found, too.  Presumably there's some trick that can be used?  From speaking with somebody else using the Word library here they've also found it very hard to use.